# Not able to capture full screen from secondary Monitor using Directshow

Tags: c#, directshow

I am trying to capture the screen of the PC connected to my PC via HDMI using Direct-show. **I am using capture card  as the hardware and Direct show's sample grabber method to  render those captured frames.**

The issue is I am not able to render the full screen of the secondary monitor on to my computer. Both PC's are of different configuration. I have tried giving different frame size values like 1366*768 but it just picks up 1280*768 I believe .

Moreover I have set the frame size to be captured as 1366*768 and even my PC is set to the same display setting still it does not render the full screen.

[**Here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34663/DirectShow-Examples-for-Using-SampleGrabber-for-Gr) is the code I am using for capturing and rendering. Capture class has  a **property called frame size** whose size has been set to 1366*768 but as soon as I do that and run the code it shows a total blank screen and when i change the setting to 1280*768 it will render the secondary monitor but won't render the full screen of it.

```
 Size size = new Size(1366, 768);
            capture.FrameSize = size;
```

where capture class has the below given property

```
public Size FrameSize
        {
            get
            {
                BitmapInfoHeader bmiHeader;
                bmiHeader = (BitmapInfoHeader) getStreamConfigSetting( videoStreamConfig, "BmiHeader" );
            //  Size size = new Size( bmiHeader.Width, bmiHeader.Height );
                Size size = new Size(1280, 768);
                return( size );
            }
            set
            {
                BitmapInfoHeader bmiHeader;
                bmiHeader = (BitmapInfoHeader) getStreamConfigSetting( videoStreamConfig, "BmiHeader" );
                bmiHeader.Width = 1280;
                bmiHeader.Height = 768;
                setStreamConfigSetting( videoStreamConfig, "BmiHeader", bmiHeader );
//#if NEWCODE
                this.videoCaps = null;
//#endif
            }       
        }
```

Any suggestions or findings that how can I capture the full screen of the secondary monitor will be really appreciated.

Comment: You should first understand if signal on HDMI cable is good, or it is already cropped or letterboxed, you cannot fix this through DirectShow. Then your DirectShow capture settings have to match the metrics of HDMI signal/mode for the capture to happen and not be black.

Comment: Roman R: I found out the solution of the above problem as the code I am using for extending display was treating my monitor(primary) as secondary one because i am using an external graphics card not an integrated one..